# Does my code get uploaded into Maven repositories?

Tags: java, maven, repository

I'm pretty new to Maven and Javafx. I am doing a project which is not open source and I don't want my codes to be made public. I was wondering if by using Maven, my codes get uploaded into Maven repositories as archetypes or in any other way. 
If so, how can I stop it?

Comment: What brought you to this conclusion? Apart from that the uploaded needs authentication which you usually don't have and why should Maven or any other build tool do such things by default?

Comment: My question may have been far from the reality, but does mean it should not be asked? As for the derivative of my conclusion, reading about Private Maven Repositories and related subjects made me wonder the aforementioned question of mine. Then I carefully checked the POM file and came across "xsi:schemaLocation" and other necessities that I now understand are unrated.
With the help of the guys who kindly answered the question, I now have a better understanding of the subject in question and I hope it can help others. 
But thank you for your comment, 
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

When you use Maven your code is packaged as jar files and put in your local repository (typically under .m2 in your home folder) on equal footing with the artifacts Maven downloads from the net.

Things only leave your machine if you explicitly upload it.  For Maven Central that is a non-trivial process you cannot do by accident.

No reason to worry.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use maven to push your artifacts to a public maven repository, but it doesn't happen out of the blue unless you put in the work to do so. In other words - maven is pretty popular for non open source Java projects too, and there's no problem using it as such.

Comment: Thank you, much obliged